# Python: "Unused variable" warning in PyDev

Tags: python, warnings, compiler-warnings

Here is my code, and there is a "compiler" warning (is that the correct term for it?) under the instantiation of `normDataSet` below:

```
def autoNorm(dataSet):
    minVals = dataSet.min(0)
    maxVals = dataSet.max(0)
    ranges = maxVals - minVals
    normDataSet = np.zeros(np.shape(dataSet)) # Warning under "normDataSet" here.
    m = dataSet.shape[0]
    normDataSet = dataSet - np.tile(minVals, (m, 1))
    normDataSet = normDataSet / np.tile(ranges, (m, 1)) 
    return normDataSet, ranges, minVals
```

The full warning in PyDev reads: `Unused variable: normDataSet`
Is there a way to eliminate this warning without having to suppress it with `@UnusedVariable`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Just my two cents but I think it's actually an IDE warning as Python does not have a compiler ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable isn't unused, but the assignment you're making is pointless, since you reassign to `normDataSet` without ever using the value you first assigned. The line flagged can be removed entirely.

Don't suppress the warning; it's there to tell you there's a problem.

Comment: Thanks! I took this code from a textbook, so I overlooked the redundant assignment. A fresh set of eyes helps because I was suspecting the IDE instead of the code! I'll let the author know to add this to their errata.